# Pyspark Split on first occurance using regex

Tags: python, regex, split, pyspark

I have a requirement to split on '=' but only by the first occurrence.

example: Consider my dataframe is below.

```
df.show()


+-----------+

|      Col|

+-----------+

|    He=l=lo|

|How=Are=you|

+-----------+
```

I want the output as

```
df_split.show()

+-----------+-------------+

|      col|          col_split|

+-----------+-------------+

|    He=l=lo|    [He,l=lo]|

|How=Are=y=ou|[How,Are=y=ou]|

+-----------+-------------+
```

I have tried to split solution as below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

df.withColumn('col_split',split('col','^(.+?)=')).show()

+-----------+----------+

|      Words|       spl|

+-----------+----------+

|    He=l=lo|  [, l=lo]|

|I am= fi=ne|[,  Are=y=ou]|

+-----------+----------+
```

Note:I tried a simple UDF with `split(col,'=',1)` since the data is huge its slow and some times hangs indefinitely.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You may consider splitting into two columns with `df.withColumn("spl_before", regexp_extract("col_split", "^([^=]*)=", 1)).withColumn("spl_after", regexp_extract("col_split", "=(.*)", 1)).show()`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go try this, you can try this `regex`

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([["He=l=lo"],["How=Are=you"]],["Col"])
>>> df.show()
+-----------+
|        Col|
+-----------+
|    He=l=lo|
|How=Are=you|
+-----------+
>>> df.withColumn("col_split", split(col("col"), "(?<=^[^=]*)\\=")).show()

+-----------+--------------+
|        Col|     col_split|
+-----------+--------------+
|    He=l=lo|    [He, l=lo]|
|How=Are=you|[How, Are=you]|
+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [`substring_index`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) for that:

```
df.withColumn("col_split",
              array(substring_index(col("Col"), "=", 1), substring_index(col("Col"), "=", -2))
              ).show()
```

Gives:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|        Col|     col_split|
+-----------+--------------+
|    He=l=lo|    [He, l=lo]|
|How=Are=you|[How, Are=you]|
+-----------+--------------+
```